# AWK sum column in file specify as a argument

Tags: awk

I want to write a script that sums up my column in the file. The numbers of columns he wants to give as an argument. It may be several. I do not know how to solve this with awk so that sums up several columns.

```
cat count.txt | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

For example, this code sum one column, as do the number of columns is not constant? Only it depends on what the user put?

Eg. I would like to sum column number 2, 5, 1 or in next time 6,3,2 etc.

Comment: Do you want a single variable to hold the totals of all those columns, or do you want each column to have their own sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't need `cat` -- awk knows how to read files.

You'll want to pass the columns in as a comma-separated string using the `-v` option, and then in awk's BEGIN block, split the string

```
awk -v cols="2,5,1" '
    BEGIN {n = split(cols, ary, /,/); sum=0}
    {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) sum += $(ary[i])}
    END {print sum}
' count.txt
```

`split` returns the number of elements generated, so be sure to save this value so you can loop over the array later.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How to place list of arguments of bash script like `$@`?  Just `cols=$@` and split by space?

Comment: No problem. Use `-v cols="*"` -- note you must use `$*` and the double quotes exactly as shown. Than `split(cols, ary)` -- whitespace is the default field separator

Comment: at which point I should to insert a list of arguments from `$@`?

Comment: typo in my previous comment. use `-v cols="$*"` -- use `"$*"` not `"$@"` so that the expanded value is a single word. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12314451/7552 for more info

Comment: Ok, thanks. It works. I have one more question. How to sum all numbers in all columns in file?

Comment: short answer: `sum[ary[i]] += $(ary[i])`